# How split a string in java and assign a hyperlink to each separated value

Tags: java

I am getting the following from DB with the respective id's as shown in the below picture:

[image: from db]

I need to separate the location_names with their respective location id's so that I can update each location individually.
Finally I need something like this:

```
 <a href="updateLocation/1">loc1</a>
 <a href="updateLocation/2">loc2</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I din get you?

Comment: You can split a string with String.split().

Comment: location id and location name will both size will be equal?

Comment: Yes @Tejal they will be equal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If location id  size and  location  name size both are equal then you can try following code snippet

```
    String ids = "1,2,3,4,5";
    String locations = "loc1,loc2,loc3,loc4,loc5";

    String[] idArr = ids.split(",");
    String[] locationArr = locations.split(",");

    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= locationArr.length - 1; i++) {
        data.put(idArr[i], locationArr[i]);

        System.out.println("<a href=" + "updateLocation/" + idArr[i] + ">" + locationArr[i] + "</a>");

    }
    System.out.println("-----map data--------" + data);
```

Comment: just make sure size of  location id and location name should be equal else it will give ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

You can create map like this from your data.

```
String id = "3,2,1,5,4";
String location = "loc3,loc2,loc1,loc5,loc4";
String[] ids = id.split(",");
String[] locations = location.split(",");

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    map.put(ids[i], locations[i]);
}
```

By iterating map in jsp you can create link as you want.